# Get parameters of public symbols in WinDBG

Tags: windbg, debug-symbols, name-mangling

I'm debugging an application with WinDBG and the PDB files contain only public symbols, so the "k" command shows only the function names in a call stack. How I can show parameters, too?

I already figured out that I can show decorated names by enabling ".symopt- 2",
so I can use the "undname.exe" that comes with Visual Studio to get the parameters from a decorated name. Essentially, I want that WinDBG does the same thing. Is that possible? Is there a plugin for this?

Many thanks in advance!

(PS: Visual Studio shows the parameters, so it probably does this by default)

Comment: It's not an issue of the symbols, it's a matter of the command. Use `kb` to show the parameters in 32 bit. Note that in 64 bit, registers are used for passing parameters and `kb` cannot do that for you.

Comment: I don't want to see the actual parameter values, but the formal parameters (terminology confusion). Example: void f(int a); .... f(5). What "kb" gives me is the value 5. What I want to see is that function f takes a parameter of type int.

Answer (score 4):

the tool **dbh.exe** in windbg package has an **undec command and a -d** `command line option` which you can leverage by loading the exe in a sepearte cmd line window at the same base address as in windbg and examining like below this involves manual copy pasting of the decorated name

an example

```
dbh -d classmagic.exe

classmagic [1000000]: b 1350000  <-- base as loaded in windbg 

classmagic [1350000]: a 1351000

?somecrap@@YAHHMND@Z
   name : ?somecrap@@YAHHMND@Z
   addr :  1351000
   size : 0
  flags : 400000
   type : 0
modbase :  1350000
  value :        0
    reg : 0
  scope : SymTagNull (0)
    tag : SymTagPublicSymbol (a)
  index : 1

classmagic [1350000]: undec ?somecrap@@YAHHMND@Z

?somecrap@@YAHHMND@Z =
int __cdecl somecrap(int,float,double,char)

classmagic [1350000]:
```

if you need automation and can accept or improve regex as approriate
1) you should have the gnuwin32 port of unix/linux **sed.exe** in path (to strip modname from k1 output )
2) instead of undname.exe you should have **[vc++filt](http://ishiboo.com/~danny/Projects/vc++filt/)** in path
3) you should be able to run the windbg **.shell** command
4) redecorate the function name with **.symopt- symopt_undname**
5) run this one liner  **.shell -ci "k1" sed s/.*!//g | vc++filt**

**k1** use only one frame (`top of stack`)
**.shell -ci** takes a windbg command and `passes the commands output to an external application`
sed strips the module name and the bang character **xxxxx!** and pipes it to **vc++filt**
vc++filt de-mangles the symbol name and returns  back the formal 
function name to windbg screen

an example below

```
0:000> k1
ChildEBP RetAddr  
001cf904 013513b5 classmagic!?somecrap@@YAHHMND@Z
0:000> .shell -ci "k1" sed s/.*!//g | vc++filt
ChildEBP RetAddr  
int __cdecl somecrap(int,float,double,char)
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the type of symbols available.

Public symbols, don't contain information about formal parameters. This is [explained to great length here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553493(v=vs.85).aspx) (note: this page is also available in the windbg help file, search for "Public and Private Symbols").

> Functions, on the other hand, are included both in the private symbol
>   data and public symbol table, but while the private symbol data
>   includes the function name, address, FPO records, input parameter
>   names and types, and output type, **the public symbol table includes
>   just the function name, address, and FPO record**.

`x`, `ln` (or some other commands like `.fnent`) should give you this kind of information.

Example with notepad:

```
0:004> x notepad!RestoreFmt
00007ff7`471251a8 notepad!RestoreFmt (<no parameter info>)

0:004> ln notepad!RestoreFmt
Browse module
Set bu breakpoint

(00007ff7`471251a8)   notepad!RestoreFmt   |  (00007ff7`471251f8)   notepad!SaveFile
Exact matches:
    notepad!RestoreFmt (<no parameter info>)
```

Note that `<no parameter info>` clearly states that the symbols don't contain the required information.

The same applied to another program with private symbolic information:

C++ code:

```
bool DiskReaderWriter::ReadDisk(off_t offset, size_t size_to_read, std::vector<BYTE>& buffer)
```

Windbg :

```
0:001> x drive_rw!DiskReaderWriter::ReadDisk
00000000`00d202c0 drive_rw!DiskReaderWriter::ReadDisk (long, unsigned int, class std::vector<unsigned char,std::allocator<unsigned char> > *)

0:001> ln drive_rw!DiskReaderWriter::ReadDisk
Browse module
Set bu breakpoint

g:\app\cpp\drive_rw\diskreaderwriter.cpp(72)
(00000000`00d202c0)   drive_rw!DiskReaderWriter::ReadDisk   |  (00000000`00d20410)   drive_rw!std::_Iterator_base12::_Adopt
Exact matches:
    drive_rw!DiskReaderWriter::ReadDisk (long, unsigned int, class std::vector<unsigned char,std::allocator<unsigned char> > *)
```

Comment: @nietsa the decorated symbol name exists in public pdbs also  and is not reflected with  x . ln . or .fnent see my answer for  retrieving the parameter information from the decorated symbol name